# Add 2 hours to date format in php

Tags: php, date

I tried to add +2 hours to date function visualization in php (wordpress).
my code is

```
function my_last_login( ) {
return 'j F Y H:i';
}
```

it prints 21 october 2015 15:36 i want 21 october 2015 17:36
I already tried with strtotime but i'm not good in php.
i tried

```
function my_last_login( ) {
return ('j F Y H:i',strtotime('+2 hours'));
}
```

Comment: This isn't very clear. Where is this function called? Calling `my_last_login` will simply echo `j F Y H:i`.

Comment: The line `return 'j F Y H:i';` just returns that string, so the time information must be added somewhere else - you'll need to modify the code there. But your requirement makes me a bit suspicious, are you trying to work around time zone issues?

Comment: @giangi90 Your code is fine, just add `date` right after `return`. Also, use the second code and you won't need to set timezone.

Comment: now it prints something like 21 +02002015-10-21T15:36:06+00:00312015bEurope/RomeWed, 21 Oct 2015 15:36:06 +0000 2015 18:48

Comment: @giangi90 in that case, you should **not** "fix" the problem by messing with the output, trenccan's solution may help.

Answer (score 3):

What about to find the right timezone and put it in to the `date_default_timezone_set()` function? Here is the list of the [timezones](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php). You only need to find the timezone that is +2 hours from your time.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) you can do something similar to this :

```
<?php
    $date = new DateTime('2000-01-01');
    $date->add(new DateInterval('P2H'));
    echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') "\n";
    ?>
```

or 
You can set your date time to your timezone date to avoid adding or subtracting 
look at this [page](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) for examples and here is a snippet code from the page :

```
// Specified date/time in the specified time zone.
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay here is another alternative answer for this one. Just use this function in your sourcecode.

```
 function dateAddAnHour($date = null, $howManyHours = 1, $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s') {
    $new_date = new \DateTime($date);
    $new_date->modify('+'.$howManyHours.' hour');      
    return $new_date->format($format);
 }
```

**Usage**

```
echo dateAddAnHour('2018-07-20 01:00:00', 2); // Outputs 2018-07-20 03:00:00
echo dateAddAnHour('2018-07-20 23:00:00', 2); // Outputs 2018-07-21 01:00:00
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

If `my_last_login` is only `return`ing a date format `string` then you will not be able to add 2 hours inside the function.

You will have to find where `my_last_login` is being called in order to modify the date.

An example of date modification:

```
$date_format_string = 'j F Y H:i';
$test_date_string = "21 October 2015 16:37";
$test_date_timestamp = strtotime($test_date_string);
$test_date = date($date_format_string, $test_date_timestamp);
$future_date_timestamp = strtotime($test_date_string . " +2 hours");

echo "Test Date (string): " . $test_date_string;
echo "<br>";
echo "Test Date Timestamp (integer): " . $test_date_timestamp;
echo "<br>";
echo "Future Date Timestamp (+2 Hours): " . $future_date_timestamp;
echo "<br>";
echo "Future Date (string): " . date($date_format_string, $future_date_timestamp);
```

php [`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) accepts two arguments, `string $format` and `int $timestamp`; it returns a formatted date string.

php [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) accepts two arguments, `string $time` and `int $timestamp`; it returns a timestamp on success which would be perfect for `date`

The above would output the following:

```
Test Date (string): 21 October 2015 16:37
Test Date Timestamp (integer): 1445445420
Future Date Timestamp (+2 Hours): 1445452620
Future Date (string): 21 October 2015 18:37
```